# Unable to download the Jenkins plugins running on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: docker, jenkins, google-cloud-platform, jenkins-plugins

I'm running the Jenkins as a Docker container on a Virtual Machine on Google Cloud Platform. On the very first screen of setup, I can see that a lot of plugins did not install in my Jenkins server? 
Please let me know how to resolve this issue? Is it something due to with the security on the cloud by default which restricts downloading of plugins?

Refer following link for screenshot:-
https://storage.googleapis.com/mydockerissues/Jenkins%20Plugins%20Issue.PNG

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me when running Jenkins on Docker on my local machine. To get everything to install I had to keep retrying. It took several retries but eventually I got everything installed.

I'm not sure why this is the case. Maybe it fails downloads whose dependencies aren't installed yet?